# Using Ruby on Rails and Savon gem to send a shipment request, very specific issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, soap-client, savon

after reading documentation several times and browsing the internet, I decided to ask for help. I have to make a SOAP request, sending a complicated object that looks like this :

http://mountainstream.ms/so1.png

http://mountainstream.ms/so2.png

http://mountainstream.ms/so3.png

I try to use a Ruby instance variable to hold the data in a hash. It looks like this:

```
@@order[:pickupDate] = { pickupDate: '', readyTime: '08:00', closeTime: '20:00'}
@@order[:service] = { shipper: shipper, packaging: packaging }
package = [weight, length, height, width, shape, packaging, packageValue]
@@order[:packages] = package
@@order[:packageServiceOptions] = { insurance: insurance, cod: cod, description:   description, remarks: remarks }
@@order[:inpostMachines] = { senderMachine: '', recipientMachine: '', alternativeRecipientMachine: '' }
@@order[:sender] = { contact: { companyName: sender_company_name,
                                  personName: sender_name,
                                  phoneNumber: sender_phone,
                                  emailAddress: sender_email
                                },
                       address: { street: sender_street,
                                  postalCode: sender_po,
                                  city: sender_city,
                                  stateOrProvinceCode: sender_state,
                                  country: sender_country
                        }} 
@@order[:recipient] = { contact: { companyName:  rec_company_name,
                                     personName: rec_name,
                                     phoneNumber: rec_phone,
                                     emailAddress: rec_email
                                   },
                          address: { street: rec_street,
                                     postalCode: rec_po,
                                     city: rec_city,
                                     stateOrProvinceCode: rec_state,
                                     country: rec_country
                         }}

response = @@client.call(:rate_shipment, message: { shipementToEvaluate: @@order, 
apiKey: apiKey, sessionId: @@sessionId})
```

When I send this, the response includes errors:

```
`<h1>CException</h1> <p>Argument 1 passed to ShipmentValidator::__construct() must be an instance of Shipment, null given, called in /api/protected/controllers/ShipServiceController.php on line 252 and defined</p>`
```

I tried to rearrange the hash to no avail, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sending an invalid request? Also, I would check out line 252 and ensure that ShipmentValidator::__construct() is an instance of Shipment

Comment: The canonical answer to address this type of question: Have you tried to create a valid SOAP message using SoapUI? Could you send successfully your message to the service? If the answer is YES, then we can help to build a similar working SOAP message using Ruby and Savon (and maybe other tools).

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded SoapUI, but it doesn't import the WSDL  https://stskurier.com/api/v1/ , throwing "Error loading [https://stskurier.com/api/v1/]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: java.io.CharConversionException: Characters larger than 4 bytes are not supported: byte 0xbf implies a length of more than 4 bytes"